# setting dynamic $_POST name with filtering value

Tags: php, post

i try to clear all `$_POST` on first line of my php files
i use function  to clear it with `tirm` , `stripslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
function filter($data) {
$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
return $data;
}




  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$test="['".$key."']";  
$_POST.$test=array(filter($value));     
    }
```

i try here to get all `$_POST` name  and value 
and re set post with new value

Comment: What is that you're trying to do?

Comment: i try to secure all $_POST into all scripts

Comment: That's not how you access an associative array's elements in php. You just do `$_POST[$key] = ...` if that's not the problem you're having, you should still know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you saw how to do something similar to this and are thinking it needs to be run like a string. That is not the case. I think, instead, this is the code that you're looking to achieve:

```
<?php

function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = mysql_real_escap_string(stripslashes($data));
    }
    return $data;
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = filter($value);     
}
```

There's lots of great [help on arrays at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). And if you're looking for something a little more advanced I would suggest looking into [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). You're code would be more performant and look something like this:

```
<?php

function filter(&$data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = mysql_real_escap_string(stripslashes($data));
    }
}

array_walk ($_POST, 'filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice simple way to apply your function to your post array:

```
function filter(&$data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = mysql_real_escap_string(stripslashes($data));
    }
    return $data;
}

array_walk($_POST, 'filter');
```